# convert multidimensional array to json format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I just started learning about JSON. I have to create a static multidimensional array which later required to convert to json encode. Now I get confused in creating multiple array. The below are the code that I have tried. I should have many post and author in this array. But it is printing only single post and author. I am not sure where I exactly did mistake.

```
<?php
    $data['post']= array(
        'title' => 'This is title',
        'message' =>'This is message',
        'datetime' => 'This is date time',
        'bannerImage' =>''
        );
    $data['author']= array(
        'authorName' => 'Jason Bourne',
        'userType' => 'Registered User',
        'address' => 'New York',
        'profilePic' => 'Profile picture'
        );
    $data['post']= array(
        'title' => 'This is title1',
        'message' =>'This is message1',
        'datetime' => 'This is date time1',
        'bannerImage' =>''
        );
    $data['author']= array(
        'authorName' => 'Jason Bourne1',
        'userType' => 'Registered User1',
        'address' => 'New York1',
        'profilePic' => 'Profile picture1'
        );
    $datas = array($data);
    $rss = (object) array('data'=>$datas);
    $json = json_encode($rss);
    echo $json;
```

Comment: You will probably notice in the near future that your `$data` declarations will be overwriting previous declarations because you are reusing the same keys.  ...your `$data` array will only have two subarrays: 'post' (once) and 'author' (once).

Comment: @mickmackusa yes how can i solve that

Comment: Post, in your question, how you are generating these arrays.  They _can_ be simply auto-indexed by php using `[]`, but let's see what you are doing to get here.

Comment: You can't have multiple keys with same name, in your above array post field and author field are defined twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you can check the [live demo](https://eval.in/798741)

```
<?php

    $data['post']= array(
        'title' => 'This is title',
        'message' =>'This is message',
        'datetime' => 'This is date time',
        'bannerImage' =>''
        );
    $data['author']= array(
        'authorName' => 'Jason Bourne',
        'userType' => 'Registered User',
        'address' => 'New York',
        'profilePic' => 'Profile picture'
        );
    $datas[] = $data;
    $data['post']= array(
        'title' => 'This is title1',
        'message' =>'This is message1',
        'datetime' => 'This is date time1',
        'bannerImage' =>''
        );
    $data['author']= array(
        'authorName' => 'Jason Bourne1',
        'userType' => 'Registered User1',
        'address' => 'New York1',
        'profilePic' => 'Profile picture1'
        );
    $datas[] = $data;
    $json = json_encode(array('data'=>$datas));
    echo $json;
```

Comment: I am getting the same result

Comment: @SS, sorry it's my fault, check it now

Comment: thank you very much. that is what i was trying. i tried array_push before but no idea what went wrong. anyways thank you