# group by json output in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "college");
$query = "SELECT branch, year,semester, COUNT(*) count FROM students GROUP BY branch,year,semester;";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$rows= mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

this is my output:

[{"branch":"cse","year":"1","semester":"1","count":"4"},{"branch":"cse","year":"2","semester":"1","count":"1"},{"branch":"cse","year":"2","semester":"2","count":"2"},{"branch":"cse","year":"2","semester":"4","count":"1"},{"branch":"cse","year":"3","semester":"2","count":"1"},{"branch":"cse","year":"3","semester":"3","count":"2"},{"branch":"cse","year":"4","semester":"3","count":"1"},{"branch":"cse","year":"4","semester":"4","count":"2"},
{"branch":"ece","year":"1","semester":"4","count":"2"},{"branch":"ece","year":"2","semester":"2","count":"2"},{"branch":"ece","year":"2","semester":"3","count":"1"},{"branch":"ece","year":"3","semester":"1","count":"1"},{"branch":"ece","year":"3","semester":"3","count":"2"},{"branch":"ece","year":"4","semester":"2","count":"2"},{"branch":"ece","year":"4","semester":"4","count":"2"},
{"branch":"eee","year":"1","semester":"1","count":"1"},{"branch":"eee","year":"1","semester":"4","count":"1"},{"branch":"eee","year":"2","semester":"1","count":"1"},{"branch":"eee","year":"2","semester":"2","count":"3"},{"branch":"eee","year":"2","semester":"3","count":"2"},{"branch":"eee","year":"2","semester":"4","count":"1"},{"branch":"eee","year":"3","semester":"1","count":"1"},{"branch":"eee","year":"3","semester":"2","count":"1"},{"branch":"eee","year":"3","semester":"3","count":"4"},{"branch":"eee","year":"3","semester":"4","count":"3"},{"branch":"eee","year":"4","semester":"2","count":"3"},{"branch":"eee","year":"4","semester":"3","count":"2"},{"branch":"eee","year":"4","semester":"4","count":"1"}]

but i want output like this:

```
{"cse":

[{"year":"1","semester":"1","count":"4"},
{"year":"2","semester":"1","count":"1"},
{"year":"2","semester":"2","count":"2"},
{"year":"2","semester":"4","count":"1"},
{"year":"3","semester":"2","count":"1"},
{"year":"3","semester":"3","count":"2"},
{"year":"4","semester":"3","count":"1"},
{"year":"4","semester":"4","count":"2"}],

"ece":

[{"year":"1","semester":"4","count":"2"},
{"year":"2","semester":"2","count":"2"},
{"year":"2","semester":"3","count":"1"},
{"year":"3","semester":"1","count":"1"},
{"year":"3","semester":"3","count":"2"},
{"year":"4","semester":"2","count":"2"},
{"year":"4","semester":"4","count":"2"}],

"eee":

[{"year":"1","semester":"1","count":"1"},
{"year":"1","semester":"4","count":"1"},
{"year":"2","semester":"1","count":"1"},
{"year":"2","semester":"2","count":"3"},
{"year":"2","semester":"3","count":"2"},
{"year":"2","semester":"4","count":"1"},
{"year":"3","semester":"1","count":"1"},
{"year":"3","semester":"3","count":"4"},
{"year":"3","semester":"4","count":"3"},
{"year":"4","semester":"2","count":"3"},
{"year":"4","semester":"3","count":"2"},
{"year":"4","semester":"4","count":"1"}]}
```

suggest any other ways to display above output

Comment: maybe duplicated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014428/convert-multidimensional-array-to-json-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than do a `mysqli_fetch_all`, it may be easier (and might be quicker) to fetch each row at a time and put it into the correct format in one operation...

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$output = [];
while ( $rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $output [$rows['branch']][] = ["year" => $rows['year'], 
                   "semester" => $rows['semester'], 
                   "count" => $rows['count']];
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: thanks...its working bro...is there any way display output in more attractive way in json format?

Comment: You can use `json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`

Comment: no difference with json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)

Comment: @MaheshRamineedi please define "attractive" then...what do you mean by that exactly? What are you wanting to see? JSON is just data for transmission or storage, it's not really meant for displaying nicely, so beyond the "pretty print" setting (and that might not have much effect, depending exactly what client you're using to receive the data) there aren't really any options.